# Convert any date String to a particular date format String

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

To be very specific , I have a string of date in any format and I want to convert it to String as "20121112" any help please.?..I know this may be done through SimpleDateFormatter.

Comment: Do you mean that the input format is changing?

Comment: *Any format* can't work - how can you know if 12/11/2012 is 11-December or 12-November for example? So you need to somewhat limit the input formatting options...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no magic you can apply here. First you need to work out what the date format is, then you need to convert it.  For example, is 01/02/03 the 1st of Feb 1903 or 2003, or is it the 2nd of Jan 2003, or 3rd of Feb 2001. You decide. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Something like this...

```
SimpleDateFormat source = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/YYYY");  // British format
SimpleDateFormat target = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMdd");

String oldDate = "06/12/2012";
String newDate = target.format(source.parse(oldDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

it can't be done, because you have to specify the order of day,month.

Romanian date  string:   "30.01.2013"
Humgarian date string:  "2013.01.30"
US date string:         "01.30.2013"

And you want to "recognized" from any format...

At least must know the formatting, which isn't from any format anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the date into a formatter. One way of doing this is like this:

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
FastDateFormat dateFormatter = FastDateFormat.getInstance("yyyyMMdd");
System.out.println(dateFormatter.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the date format (i.e. mm/dd or dd/mm), something like so will work:

```
// my date in String format in yyyy/mm/dd
String myDate = "20121206";

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); // format
cal.setTime(sdf.parse(myDate));
```

This will convert your string into a `Calendar`, `Date#parse` is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

like the date -d "Fri Apr  1" +%D
Only for java?

Comment: Please don't add questions to the original poster as answers. Instead consider posting your question as a comment to the original question itself.